# Why does groupby operations behave differently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

When using [pandas groupby functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html#computations-descriptive-stats) and manipulating the output after the groupby, I've noticed that some functions behave differently in terms of what is returned as the index and how this can be manipulated.

Say we have a dataframe with the following information:

```
    Name   Type  ID
0  Book1  ebook   1
1  Book2  paper   2
2  Book3  paper   3
3  Book1  ebook   1
4  Book2  paper   2
```

if we do

```py
df.groupby(["Name", "Type"]).sum()
```

we get a `DataFrame`:

```
             ID
Name  Type     
Book1 ebook   2
Book2 paper   4
Book3 paper   3
```

which contains a MultiIndex with the columns used in the groupby:

```py
MultiIndex([('Book1', 'ebook'),
            ('Book2', 'paper'),
            ('Book3', 'paper')],
           names=['Name', 'Type'])
```

and one column called `ID`.

but if I apply a `size()` function, the result is a `Series`:

```py
Name   Type 
Book1  ebook    2
Book2  paper    2
Book3  paper    1
dtype: int64
```

And at last, if I do a `pct_change()`, we get only the resulting DataFrame column:

```py
    ID
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   0.0
4   0.0
```

TL;DR. I want to know why some functions return a `Series` whilst some others a `DataFrame` as this made me confused when dealing with different operations within the same DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outputs are different because the **aggregations** are different, and those are what mostly control what is returned. Think of the array equivalent. The data are the same but one "aggregation" returns a single scalar value, the other returns an array the same size as the input

```
import numpy as np
np.array([1,2,3]).sum()
#6

np.array([1,2,3]).cumsum()
#array([1, 3, 6], dtype=int32)
```

The same thing goes for aggregations of a DataFrameGroupBy object. All the first part of the `groupby` does is create a mapping from the DataFrame to the groups. Since this doesn't really do anything there's no reason why the same groupby with a different operation needs to return the same type of output (see above).

```
gp = df.groupby(["Name", "Type"])
# Haven't done any aggregations yet...
```

The other **important** part here is that we have a **DataFrame**GroupBy object. There are also **Series**GroupBy objects, and that difference can change the return.

```
gp
#<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object>
```

---

So what happens when you aggregate?

With a `DataFrameGroupBy` when you choose an aggregation (like `sum`) that collapses to a single value per group the return will be a DataFrame where the indices are the unique grouping keys. The return is a `DataFrame` because we provided a DataFrameGroupBy object. DataFrames can have multiple columns and had there been another numeric column it would have aggregated that too, necessitating the DataFrame output.

```
gp.sum()
#             ID
#Name  Type     
#Book1 ebook   2
#Book2 paper   4
#Book3 paper   3
```

On the other hand if you use a SeriesGroupBy object (select a single column with `[]`) then you'll get a Series back, again with the index of unique group keys.

```
df.groupby(["Name", "Type"])['ID'].sum()
|------- SeriesGroupBy ----------|

#Name   Type 
#Book1  ebook    2
#Book2  paper    4
#Book3  paper    3
#Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

For aggregations that return arrays (like `cumsum`, `pct_change`) a DataFrameGroupBy will return a DataFrame and a SeriesGroupBy will return a Series. But the index is no longer the unique group keys. This is because that would make little sense; typically you'd want to do a calculation within the group and then **assign the result back** to the original DataFrame. As a result the return is indexed like the original DataFrame you provided for aggregation. This makes creating these columns very simple as pandas handles all of the alignment

```
df['ID_pct_change'] = gp.pct_change()

#    Name   Type  ID  ID_pct_change
#0  Book1  ebook   1            NaN  
#1  Book2  paper   2            NaN   
#2  Book3  paper   3            NaN   
#3  Book1  ebook   1            0.0  # Calculated from row 0 and aligned.
#4  Book2  paper   2            0.0
```

---

But what about `size`? That one is a bit *weird*. The `size` of a group is a scalar. It doesn't matter how many columns the group has or whether values in those columns are missing, so sending it a DataFrameGroupBy or SeriesGroupBy object is irrelevant. As a result `pandas` will always return a `Series`. Again being a group level aggregation that returns a scalar it makes sense to have the return indexed by the unique group keys.

```
gp.size()
#Name   Type 
#Book1  ebook    2
#Book2  paper    2
#Book3  paper    1
#dtype: int64
```

---

Finally for completeness, though aggregations like `sum` return a single scalar value it can often be useful to bring those values back to the every row for that group in the original DataFrame. However the return of a normal `.sum` has a different index, so it won't align. You could `merge` the values back on the unique keys, but `pandas` provides the ability to `transform` these aggregations. Since the intent here is to bring it back to the original DataFrame, the Series/DataFrame is indexed like the original input

```
gp.transform('sum')
#   ID
#0   2    # Row 0 is Book1 ebook which has a group sum of 2
#1   4
#2   3
#3   2    # Row 3 is also Book1 ebook which has a group sum of 2
#4   4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a dedicated and didactic response.

Answer (score 3):

From the document

[Size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

> ```
> Returns
> Series
> Number of rows in each group.
> ```

---

For the `sum` , since you did not pass the column for sum, so it will return the  data frame without the groupby key

```
df.groupby(["Name", "Type"])['ID'].sum()  # return Series
```

---

Function like `diff` and `pct_change` is not agg, it will return the value with the same `index` as original dataframe, for `count` , `mean`, `sum` they are agg, return with the value and `groupby` key as index

Comment: I see, but is there a reason for the lack of standard? Wouldn't it be easier if the operations returned the same structure?

Comment: @GabrielZiegler it depends on the function, for example, diff will return every row, but sum will consider the whole groupby value as one output.