# pd.groupby gives multiple rows per unique value in grouping column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `dataframe` (more specifically, a document-term matrix) where the last column is "YEAR". There are five unique years in the column: 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020. This is confirmed by:

```
In [1]: len(set(df.YEAR))
Out[1]: 5
```

However, when I run the code

```
df.groupby(df.YEAR).head()
```

The resulting `dataframe.groupby` object has 25 rows: the first 5 rows have YEAR = 2016, the second 5 rows have YEAR = 2017, etc.

First, is there any way to make the result a new `dataframe` instead of a `dataframe.groupby` object?

Second, why are there 5 rows per year instead of 1? And how do I make it so there's just one row per year?

If I change the YEAR column to DATE (with `datetime` values) instead and use `df.groupby(df.DATE.dt.year)`, I still end up with 25 rows, with the first 5 rows having the following values in the DATE column: 2016-01-01, 2016-01-02, 2016-01-03, 2016-01-04, 2016-01-05

I've tried `df.groupby(df.YEAR).nunique()`, and while this results in a `dataframe` with 5 rows, it doesn't properly aggregate word counts.

I also tried setting the index to a DatetimeIndex with `df.set_index(df.DATE)` , and despite the fact that the DATE column is confirmed to be datetime:

```
In [2]: df.dtypes
Out[2]: DATE         datetime64[ns]
```

When I try `df.resample('Y')` or `pd.Grouper` or anything similar, I get `TypeError: Only valid with` DatetimeIndex`,` TimedeltaIndex`or`PeriodIndex`, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`

What should I do? This seems like it should be simple but `groupby` isn't working how I would expect it to.

Comment: `head()` defaults to 5 rows; you grab the `head` of each group of years, So 5 groups x 5 rows per group = 25 rows, which is what you see. Aggregations don't necessarily collapse to a single value per group, it depends what the aggregation function is. You can read a bit about the logic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61810108/why-does-groupby-operations-behave-differently

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. I had assumed that groupby summed the values, but it doesn't. To get what I'm looking for, I had to do df.groupby(df.YEAR).sum().

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ALollz You can try this code to get a clear picture. Also, correct me if I'm wrong.
`df_groupby = df.groupby('YEAR')`. Now if you try `df_groupby.first()` then you will get all the first entries of the new data frame. Also, `df_groupby.get_group('2017')` will give all the results of the year 2017.